# Gulp error - EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: npm, sass, compilation, gulp, raspberry-pi

I would like to expose my problem here because I have been struggling for several weeks to configure Gulp stably on my Raspberry server.

When I run Gulp within my project, I always have the following error lines that appear :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvZ5.png)

The research I conducted with this concern did not lead me to anything. I was confronted with this problem three times: the first two times, I completely reinstalled the NPM extensions by having to use the --unsafe-perm prefix. This solution worked on the moment but when I had to restart Gulp, the problem reappeared. Today, even by reinstalling Gulp and NPM modules that I use, I always get these lines of errors, no matter what solutions I try, nothing is conclusive: changing permissions etc ...

Do you have any leads to tell me?

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my English, I'm French!)